# how to use sum() and multiply() to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript

So I have this challenge. I solved the first problem by creating a `sum()` to add the two numbers. The second problem was to create a `multiply()` to solve the two numbers.

However they're now asking me to use the same functions to solve the third function `sumAndMultiply()`, but it has to do it for 3 numbers, unlike `sum()` and `multiply()` where it only accepts two numbers. So I'm lost. There's another JavaScript file that tests if the functions are correct.

> Problem 3
>
> Write a function called sumAndMultiply() that takes in three numbers as separate arguments and returns an array where the first element is the sum of those three numbers, the second element is the product of those three numbers,  and the third and fourth elements are strings that EXACTLY follow this example and use the values that were input into the function:
>
> Third element: "4 and 7 and 5 sum to 16."
> Fourth element: "The product of 4 and 7 and 5 is 140."
>
> IMPORTANT DETAIL: You may not use the arithmetic operators + and * in this function. To do addition, use your sum() function, and to do multiplication, use your multiply() function that you've already created. You're going to have to be resourceful to figure out how to do this. However, you may continue to use the + operator for string concatenation.
>
> Test this function by hand in the console to get it working, and when you think it is finished, uncomment the call for the testSumAndMultiply() function and see if the test passes.
>
> Once you get the test passing, do an a-c-p cycle and synchronize the code between GitHub and your laptop. Don't forget to create a new branch for your work on the next question!

```js
function sum(a, b) { 
  let sum = a + b;
  let print = [sum, "The sum of 4 and 7 is 11."]
  return print;
}

function multiply(a, b) { //eslint-disable-line
  let multiply = a * b;
  let printM = [multiply, "The product of 5 and 9 is 45."]
  return printM;
}

// Write your code here
function sumAndMultiply(a, b, c) { //eslint-disable-line

}

// Here is the test for sumAndMultiply(); uncomment it to run it
console.log(
  sumAndMultiply(4, 7, 5)
);
```

Now, how do I solve the function `sumAndMultiply(a, b, c)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

***ASK ONE QUESTION AT A TIME*** Now see the way I created snippets. You can now ask them ONE AT A TIME

Comment: Can you please: fix the formatting, and reduce the amount of text/content so this only contains enough code to reproduce the actual problem -> [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to reuse the `sum` and `multiply` methods to make the new one and return an array so first to get the you use

```
var sum = sum(sum(a, b)[0], c)[0];
```

First you add `a` and `b` by `sum(a, b)`. This returns an array `[sum, message]`.

You get the sum by getting the element at index `[0]` of this array and again send it to the sum function with `c` i.e. `sum(sum(a, b)[0], c)`. This returns you the final array with the sum of `a, b and c` and the message.

You do the same with the multiply function as

```
var product = multiply(multiply(a, b)[0], c)[0];
```